# Simple Jquery/Ajax loading not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay, so I'm trying to make a simple content loader which will evolve into a chat program. As of now I can't even get Jquery's .load() function to work though.

This is the important part my main file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#messages").load('/ajax-chat-load.php');
        });
    </script>

<div id="#messages">[No messages]</div>
```

And this is whats in /ajax-chat-load.php

```
echo "Hotdogs are tasty";
```

Now if my understanding is correct it the main file should call ajax-chat-load.php to load the html inside that to the #messages div when the document is done loading. But the #messages div just keeps the message [no messages].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put a `#` in front of the id in html. So do your `messages` div like this:

```
<div id="messages">[No messages]</div>
```

Your jQuery code looks fine (you *do* put a `#` in front of the id in the css path you pass to jQuery).

Comment: Oh, wow. Duh, I'm so stupid rofl. Thank you for pointing that out. I can't believe I didn't notice that before posting:< lol

Answer (score 2):

**# represents id. you can not use it as id = '#messages'**

change your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#messages").load('/ajax-chat-load.php');
        });
    </script>
```

**`<div id="messages">[No messages]</div>`**

Hope this helps.